# display the custom message instead of the detailed message on the webpage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The below html code accepts only numbers as input, but i noticed in some scenarios randomly it is accepting characters also , scenarios like when type digits and enter backspace and then type character it is accepting the letters.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="digitalId" ng-model="data.digitalId" placeholder="digits can only be entered"> </div>
```

When user submits the form, the above field value is stored in the database whose column is of type integer. But when it accepts the characters and the form is submitted, it is showing the error message on the screen but the message is detailed message which says about the DTO object and the property type. I want to show the custom message as "Only numbers are allowed" when user submits the form and the field has some characters in it. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is pure javascript based so it can be used with angular as well without jquery usage

```js
function validate(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  key = String.fromCharCode( key );
  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
  if( !regex.test(key) ) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;
    if(theEvent.preventDefault) {
    console.log("only numbers allowed");
    theEvent.preventDefault();
  }
   
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="digitalId" ng-model="data.digitalId" placeholder="digits can only be entered" onkeypress="validate(event)"> </div>
```

[A reference from this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/469419/6517383)